# margin-top: сдвинуть элемент на текщую высоту

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не знаем высоту блока, но блок необходимо сдвинуть вверх на столько, какова текущая высота. Такое возможно?

```css
:root {
  --hd: clamp(45px, 8%, 90px);
}

.rd {
   width: 200px;
   height: 1000px;
}

.block {
    background-color: #f00;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.child {
    height: var(--hd);
    background-color: #00f;
    margin-top: calc(var(--hd) * -1);
}
```

```html
<div class='rd'>
   <div class="block"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Так к примеру, чем больше высота родителя, тем больше выглядывает синий блок из под красного фона. То есть я пытаюсь выполнить смещение блока через margin-top, относительно той высоты которую выставил на этот самый блок.

В итоге получаю, неравномерное смещение. Почему так и как быть когда нельзя прибегнуть к обсолютному позиционированию.

Comment: margin-bottom: auto

Comment: Что та у меня без изменений, как в таком случаи отрицательно сдвинуть с margin-top. На текущую высоту блока.

Answer (score 0):

вы что-то явно не то делаете. Если это коммерческий проект и за это вам должны что-то заплатить, то за  `Cumulative Layout Shift` сайт снижают в рейтинге выдачи. Решается это через JS. После того как браузер отрисовывает вашу большую картинку вы отлавливаете это событие по

```
image.onload = function(){
    //display ok
}
```

и в эту функцию задаете стиль смещения для нижнего объекта. Но это явно какая-то дикость... могу дать вам несколько причин почему это плохая идея, и лучше решать как-то иначе.